# Validating a received file using a checksum

Tags: c#, checksum

I need to pass a file using a web service (I have control over the webservice). To fulfill the security requirements I need to make sure that the passed file is not modified or corrupted. I plan to do like below.

1. Convert my file to `byte[]`
2. Calculate a hash,

   `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(stream);`
3. Pass the file

When I am passing the file (byte array) to web service, is passing my hash value a good practice?

Or do I need to follow some other process to check files? What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Just specify the checksum with the algorithm in the post header.

Comment: @Romoku-  Sorry I am not clear with what you have said. Can you please provide some example links. I am using a web service to transfer the file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a security requirement, sending the MD5 sum along with the file is probably not what you want to do: anyone who can intercept the file can also rewrite the checksum as well.

I use CRCs, instead: they are somewhat more sensitive to small changes in a file (or stream's) contents, and they are more compact and easier to compare. .NET doesn't appear to have a CRC implementation, but I found a nice one online that appears to work well, *[Calculating CRC-32 in C# and .NET](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net)*.

Does your client have the capability of computing the checksum independently on its side as well?

Comment: Yes. Client have that capability. If I return the received file checksum from the  web service to the client, so that client can verifies the file. Is that process is good to implement?

Comment: Depends on your security needs.  If your goal is 100% to verify the logical integrity of the file, what you are proposing is fine.   If it is to ensure that it hasn't been tampered with  (more security-related), I would suggest building something a bit more elaborate.